# TransientObjectException when saving object in Hibernate after adding to collection having `cascade="all, delete-orphan"`

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having trouble saving a new object with Hibernate which contains a nested collection that is mapped in hibernate as having `cascade="all, delete-orphan"`. More specifically, if I save the grandparent object it fails with the stack trace included below.

What's especially frustrating is we've come across this problem a few times, but it doesn't consistently appear in all collections we persist, only some of them and we don't know Hibernate well enough to see the common cause. Any insight here is greatly appreciated.

In general I seem to frequently have to debug into Hibernate's source when trying to track down what's going on with errors, this seems strange for such a mature library. It's also a very slow process since the Hibernate internals can be quite complex to someone who's just trying to use it.

An abbreviated version of my object classes, hibernate mapping files and a repro case are included below the stack trace.

EDIT: Using `cascade="all"` avoids the error, but loses functionality we'd rather have. What assumptions is the delete orphan cascade making that are being violated? If I were doing something invalid/illegal from Hibernate's perspective I would expect it to fail to persist at all, not only fail when delete-orphan is enabled.

### Error w/ Stack Trace

```
com.foo.server.services.db.exception.InvalidObjectException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning.Duct
    at com.foo.server.services.db.Transaction.commit(Transaction.java:33)
    at com.foo.server.services.db.service.PersistenceManager.commitTransactionIfOpen(PersistenceManager.java:83)
    at com.foo.server.services.db.service.DataService.save(DataService.java:230)
    at com.foo.server.services.db.service.DataService.save(DataService.java:188)
    at com.foo.server.model.house.TestHousePlan_JDO.testAddDistributionSystemSave(TestHousePlan_JDO.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning.Duct
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.getOrphans(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.getOrphans(PersistentList.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CollectionEntry.getOrphans(CollectionEntry.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.deleteOrphans(Cascade.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
    at com.foo.server.services.db.Transaction.commit(Transaction.java:28)
    ... 31 more
```

---

### HousePlan.java

```
public class HousePlan
{
    Long id;
    List<DistributionSystem> distributionSystems = Lists.newArrayList();
    // Other fields excluded

    public HousePlan()
    {
        distributionSystems.add(new DistributionSystem());
    }

    // getters + setters
}
```

---

### HousePlan.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.foo.server.model.house">
  <class name="HousePlan" table="house_plan">
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <list name="distributionSystems" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
      <key column="housePlanId" not-null="false" />
      <list-index column="housePlanIndex" />
      <one-to-many class="com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning.DistributionSystem" />
    </list>

    <!-- Other mappings excluded -->

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

### DistributionSystem.java

```
public class DistributionSystem
{
    Long id;
    List<Duct> ducts = Lists.newArrayList();
    // Other fields excluded

    public DistributionSystem()
    {
        ducts.add(new Duct());
        ducts.add(new Duct());
    }

    // getters + setters excluded
}
```

---

### DistributionSystem.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning">
  <class name="DistributionSystem" table="distribution_system">
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <!-- Note the usage of `cascade="all,delete-orphan"` which is the normal solution to this problem -->
    <list name="ducts" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
      <key column="distributionSystemId" not-null="false" />
      <list-index column="distributionSystemIndex" />
      <one-to-many class="com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning.Duct" />
    </list>

    <!-- Other mappings excluded -->

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

### Duct.java

```
public class Duct
{
    Long id;
    // Other fields excluded

    // Constructor excluded

    // getters + setters excluded
}
```

---

### Duct.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.foo.server.model.house.conditioning">
  <class name="Duct" table="duct">
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <!-- Other mappings excluded -->

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

### Repro case

Includes abbreviated implementation of how we are using hibernate.

```
public class ReproCase
{
    public static Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        HousePlan plan = new HousePlan();

        // This save succeeds
        plan = save(plan);

        plan.getDistributionSystems().add(new DistributionSystem());

        // This save fails
        plan = save(plan);  
    }

    public static <T> T save(T object)
    {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(session);
        transaction.begin();

        // In our full app our object inheritance hierarchy allows for the
        // call to getId() 

        // Objects with null ids are transient. Objects with non-null ids are
        // not transient, but might be detached from the persistence context so
        // here we ensure the object is attached.

        if (object.getId() != null)
        {
            object = (T)session.merge(object);
        }

        try
        {
            session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            session.merge(object);
        }


        // This is where the TransientObjectException occurs
        session.flush();

        transaction.commit();

        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into an almost identical issue recently, and I ultimately determined that the problem was not with the list itself, but with one of the objects _inside_ the list. To use the classes from the question, my `Duct` class itself contained a list of references to _other_ `Duct` objects, which were intended to have already been saved separately; due to a coding error, that inner list sometimes contained objects that had _not_ yet been saved, leading to the `TransientObjectException`. I can't tell if this was the original problem, but hopefully it will help others who come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the instantiation of the list:

```
List<Duct> ducts = Lists.newArrayList();
```

This relationship is managed by Hibernate (via proxies), it won't be able to handle a standard List...

This obviously means that you can't add values inside the constructor, you have to wait until Hibernate knows about the parent before adding the defaults:

```
DistributionSystem ds = save(new DistributionSystem());
ds.getDucts().add(new Duct());
ds.getDucts().add(new Duct());
ds.getDucts().add(new Duct());
ds = save(new DistributionSystem());
```

Comment: How does modifying the instance prior to saving to the DB work if there's no list without hibernate adding it? How do I use the class in situations were persistence isn't necessary at all for the use case?

Comment: You should add to the list after Hibernate knows about the object.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: An unfortunate idiosyncrasy of our system is that every piece of business logic is written with the assumption that the instances it work with are detached or unmanaged and are not proxy types because they break certain generic methods. This is a result of the original system being built under incorrect assumptions, but makes the requirement of relying on Hibernate proxies untenable. It would be better if we could, but it would be a large undertaking to retrofit at this point.

Comment: In that case I think you need to save the `Duct` object before adding it to your original `java.util.List`, effectively removing the cascade of the create.

Comment: That's a very inconvenient step to need to remember in a system that is otherwise comprehensive in it's automation. I'm surprised that Hibernate can't determine (or couldn't be told to assume in general) that if elements of a collection on a managed entity are transient, they need to be saved when the parent is saved.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that the underlying problem is that Hibernate is incorrectly considering the transient entity added to the persistent parent entity's collection as also being persistent, thus causing the failing call to `getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved()` inside `getOrphans()`? If that's accurate, why did the cascade from merging the persistent parent result in Hibernate incorrectly marking the still transient entities in the collection as persistent instead of actually persisting them? The docs for `merge()` say it persists transient objects and that the operation cascades.

Comment: I've done a bit of testing and I think I was barking up the wrong tree with my answer, it appears Hibernate will proxy a list even if you instantiate it yourself.  I'm a bit baffled by the error in that case, since it looks like it should all be okay.  I'll remove this answer in a while since it's just muddying the water...

Comment: @StuPointerException I think the answer and the discussion are quite interesting. It would be a pity if you deleted it. Why don't you just edit it and insert a disclaimer at the top like "Probably wrong. Left here for the historical record." ;-)